# python - add range of time as column name

Tags: python, pandas

I want to add a range of time between 2021-05-01 until the current month, let say 2021-10-01, as columns to my dataframe as below:

```
Category
A
B
C
```

The result should look like this

```
Category   2021-05-01   2021-06-01   2021-07-01   2021-08-01   2021-09-01   2021-10-01
A
B
C
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: This is doable but what is the purpose? Should all the cells have nan values or empty strings? If so you just have to create a list and loop over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) for new datetimes, if necessary dates add [`DatetimeIndex.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.date.html):

```
r = pd.date_range('2021-05-01', pd.to_datetime('now'), freq='MS').date

df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(columns=r, index=df.index))
```

Or:

```
r = pd.date_range('2021-05-01', pd.to_datetime('now'), freq='MS').date

for c in r:
    df[c] = np.nan
```

Comment: nice, it works well. Thanks!